# Linking 2 tables and outputting results in descending order then alphabetical

Tags: database, sqlite, inner-join

I have a table called wrestlers that has

```
id, wrestler_name,age
1,Tom,24
2,Fred,19
3,Michael, 28
```

I have another table called reviewers that has

```
reviewer, id,score
1,1,3
1,2,3
2,3,4
```

The reviewers each have a number corresponding to the id of the wrestlers in the wrestlers table and they score each wrestler.

I am trying to find the wrestlers with at least 200 reviews. I then want to Sort the wrestlers by the review count (high to low) then by their names in alphabetical order for those who may have the same review counts.

I know I need to use an inner join and I have been trying the following but I cannot get this to work

```
select * from(select reviewers.id, wrestlers.name, count(*) from wrestlers inner join reviewers group by reviewers.id having count(reviewers.id) >= 200) order by count(*) DESC name;
```

However this is taking forever to output the data.

Answer (score 0):

It's taking forever because the database combines every review with every wrestler because you did forget the join condition.
And you do not need the subquery:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       count(*)
FROM reviewers
JOIN wrestlers USING (id)
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) >= 200
ORDER BY count(*) DESC, name;
```